# How do I extract data from an XML file and use it in my ECL program?

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I have been trying to import data from an XML file into my ECL code for some processing. However, I am encountering the following error messages:
[Error messages encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEZFk.png)

Here is the XML data I am trying to read:
[XML data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfThT.png)

Here is a screenshot of the Spraying operation:[XML File Spray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK9kb.png)

Here is the ECL code used:
[ECL code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaIEq.png)

I have tried to read the data in the file, however I have encountered the above specified error messages.
I do not know if this is because I sprayed the data incorrectly into the HPCC cluster or if there is some other problem in my ECL code.

Therefore, I require a series of steps on spraying XML data into the HPCC cluster as well as the appropriate ECL code to read and display the data. If any mistakes are present in my approach, corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the error message, XML data and ECL code as plain text instead of posting images. You can do that just by copy'n paste here during editing your question ...

Answer (score 1):

This question is directly answered by a class exercise in our Advanced ECL Part 2 course, the only difference is your "timezones" file tag instead of the "Dataset" tag in the file for the course.

Here's your example code:

```
r := RECORD
  INTEGER2  code;
  STRING110 description;
  STRING42  zone;
END;
d := DATASET('~CLASS::BMF::IN::timezones',r,XML('timezones/area'));
OUTPUT(d);
```

HTH,

Richard